# Getting last saved object id

Tags: php, mysql, crud, fuelphp

I am using the Model_CRUD class and it's methods to save and find in database. 
The problem comes when saving new object into DB, is how to get last inserted id ?

```
User::forge($userInfo)->save(); // Save returns only bool value
```

Does this requires one query more to get last inserted id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do an extra query to fetch the last inserted id. Just try the following code:

```
$user = User::forge($userInfo);
$user->save();

$last_id = $user->id;
```

You should check the [Model_Crud](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/classes/model_crud/methods.html) documentation for further info.